# Conversion error on updating text field - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a text field. Moving data to another column and truncate because it is too long.

The update statement looks like this. (Edited)

```
UPDATE Feuil1 SET [Occupant 2] = SWITCH
(
[Occupant 2] IS NOT NULL, [Occupant 3],
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 3), mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 4), mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 5), mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 6), mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 7), mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
     (LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 2), '',
     (LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 1), '',
     [Occupant 1] LIKE '* & *', mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
     [Occupant 1] LIKE '* ET *', mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," "),30),
     (LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 0), ''
), [Occupant 1] = SWITCH
(
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 3), mid([Occupant 1],1,InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," ")),
(LEN([Occupant 1]) - LEN(REPLACE([Occupant 1], ' ', '')) = 4), mid([Occupant 1],1,InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," ")),
[Occupant 1] LIKE '* & *', (replace([Occupant 1], ' & ' & mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," ")),InStr(InStr(2,[Occupant 1]," ")), '')),
[Occupant 1] LIKE '* ET *', (replace([Occupant 1], ' & ' & mid([Occupant 1],InStr(InStr(1,[Occupant 1]," ")+1,[Occupant 1]," ")),InStr(InStr(2,[Occupant 1]," ")), ''))
)
WHERE [Occupant 1] IS NOT NULL
```

I always get conversion type error but I don't know why. I am updating a text field with it's own modified data. All the columns involved are text.

I've tried to use Val(), Cstr() functions, same result.

Additionnal informations: Some data seems to be processed, but I can't find why.

Any clues?

Comment: That updates 2 fields, `[Occupant 2]` and `[Occupant 1]`, using complex `Switch()` expressions.  Split it into 2 separate `UPDATE` statements, each of which updates only a single column.  That way at least you can determine which of the 2 `Switch()` expressions triggers the error.

Comment: In fact, both trigger the same error. Should I use a cast that I didn't listed? I'm pretty confused right now

Comment: I got lost trying to understand those `Switch()` expressions.  I suggest you try a `SELECT` query which uses them in the field list.  Then you can examine their return values and hopefully identify the values which trigger the error.  `SELECT DISTINCT` and `TypeName(Switch(...))` could be useful in that effort.

Comment: Will definitely try, thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the very beginning of your statement you have these lines:

```
UPDATE Feuil1 SET [Occupant 2] = SWITCH
(
[Occupant 2] IS NOT NULL, [Occupant 3] = [Occupant 2],
```

What you are saying here is that if [Occupant 2] IS NOT NULL then set [Occupant 2] equal to the **boolean result** of [Occupant 3] = [Occupant 2] (i.e., `True` or `False`).  I'm guessing you want to change that to either:

```
UPDATE Feuil1 SET [Occupant 2] = SWITCH
(
[Occupant 2] IS NOT NULL, [Occupant 3],
```

Or, more likely:

```
UPDATE Feuil1 SET [Occupant 2] = SWITCH
(
[Occupant 2] IS NOT NULL, [Occupant 2],
```

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake here. Thanks for finding it! However, it doesn't solve my problem, the error still persists.